# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier. Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: typescript, rollup, tsdx

I'm using [TSDX](https://tsdx.io/) to create my module, which implements rollup, and I'm running into an issue with using the module correctly in another project. The module seems to build and publish just fine, I'm able to install it in my other project, and I'm getting no errors in my code, but once I open it in browser, I get this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier. Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

I'm not sure why it's trying to treat them as relative references when they are from a module, and I'm wondering if it has to do with my directory structure or how rollup is bundling everything together. My directory structure in the module itself is as follows:

```
src
 generics
  class1.ts
  class2.ts
  class3.ts
 globals
  plugins
   plugin1.ts
   plugin2.ts
  class4.ts
 type1.ts
 interface1.ts
 index.ts
.gitignore
.npmignore
.npmrc
package-lock.json
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

Using `npm run build` creates a distribution folder with the following structure, which is then published using GitHub Packages:

```
dist
 generics
  class1.d.ts
  class2.d.ts
  class3.d.ts
 globals
  plugins
   plugin1.d.ts
   plugin2.d.ts
  class4.d.ts
 type1.d.ts
 interface1.d.ts
 module-name.cjs.development.js
 module-name.cjs.development.js.map
 module-name.cjs.production.min.js
 module-name.cjs.production.min.js.map
 module-name.esm.js
 module-name.esm.js.map
 index.d.ts
 index.js
```

Here are my import statements:

```
import {Class} from 'module-name/dist/index.d.js';
import {Plugin1} from 'module-name/dist/globals/plugins/plugin1.d.js'
import {Plugin2} from 'module-name/dist/globals/plugins/plugin2.d.js'
```

What causes this error, and how can I avoid it? Am I exporting/importing the classes from my module incorrectly? Please let me know if you need additional information, I wasn't quite sure what to provide

Comment: As the error message suggests, it probably needs to be `import {something} from './module-name/dist/...`, and so on, i.e. with a `./` prefix on the path.

Comment: Using relative references also fails, as the things I am importing are from a module. I shouldn't need to use relative references for a module anyway, right?